# askToDeeplink helper broken since March 28th?

Tags: actions-on-google

The askToDeeplink helper function seems to be broken a couple of days ago.  Prior to March 28th I was able to invoke askToDeeplink from my unpublished action in test mode.  However, something happened since the 28th and now invoking the helper gives me the following error message :

```js
{
 insertId:  "1ckduv6g8muy3da"  
 labels: {
  channel:  "preview"   
  querystream:  "GOOGLE_USER"   
  source:  "JSON_RESPONSE_VALIDATION"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/androidlinktest2/logs/actions.googleapis.com%2Factions"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-03-30T01:24:52.261359446Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   action_id:  ""    
   project_id:  "androidlinktest2"    
   version_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "assistant_action"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].possible_intents[0].input_value_data.open_url_action.open_url_action.android_app: Android app must be connected to the agent"  
 timestamp:  "2018-03-30T01:24:52.253875989Z"  
 trace:  "projects/435016350697/traces/1522373084415"  
}
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Please check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 
Add your code , what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

> Android app must be connected to the agent

Have you gone into the actions on google console & associated your android app with the assistant? See: "Connected properties" section.

https://developers.google.com/actions/console/brand-verification

Comment: Yes, I've since tried connecting my android application to my action.  When I check under "Connected Properties" I see my app name with the right package name listed.  I'm still running into the same problem.  Note that connecting the Android app to the action wasn't a requirement pre March 28th when I was running my action in test.  I think this should be the correct expectation since the developer might not want to go through with the hassle of brand verification if they're simply experimenting and/or in the process of early development

Comment: one thing I want to add is my Android app is currently unpublished in the play store.  Could this cause a problem?  I really don't want to publish the Android app to the playstore since its still in development